# How to edit row of cell?

Tags: swift, row, cell, editing

I can not turn on editing mode in the first row of the cell. I tried this code but it didn't help.

```
   public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
            if indexPath.row == 1{
                return true
            }
            return false
        }
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: First row means: `indexPath.row == 0`, it is zero based...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit first row then replace

```
if indexPath.row == 1
```

with

```
if indexPath.row == 0
```

Because `indexPath.row` starts from 0 not from 1.

Hope that will help.

**EDIT:**

Since you didn't show your complete code I am adding example code here.

check below code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tbl: UITableView!

    let arr = ["1", "2", "3"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tbl.dataSource = self
        tbl.delegate = self
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tbl.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!

        cell.textLabel?.text = self.arr[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arr.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {

        //set 0 for first cell
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

    //Need this method for delete cell
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete {
            tbl.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: updating my answer.

Comment: and one thing I want to add is that I want to edit a prototype cell in table view.

Comment: @Jack It will work. Check this demo project: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=08842465814527667694

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure your have added `UITableViewDataSource` protocol. Secondly, you may also need the following implementations.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let myAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "MY_ACTION") { (action, indexPath) in
        print("I'm here")
    }

    return [myAction]
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

}
```